# Listbox: Change list item or each row height dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

I am working on Windows Phone 8, i have a Listbox with 4 items in it.

I want to change list item or each row height dynamically.

How to achieve this ?

Below is my code:

```
<ListBox Name="TopicListbox"
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TitleDataTemplate}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     SelectionChanged="TopicListboxSelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TitleDataTemplate">
            <Grid MinHeight="90" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
            </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Dynamically? you mean runtime>

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, or else how we can do it? is there any other way ?

Comment: Are you want to item fit to row inside ListBox

Comment: @Jaihind you mean fit items to listbox height ? if yes please hel pme on that as well i might need that as well

Comment: I don't quite get your question here. Are you trying to have all items of your listbox keeping the same height dynamically, even when you add for example a bigger item?

Comment: @Damascus Its like this, i know all my items are just 2 words like `Interchange Words` , but its height is small i.e., i have set `MinHeight="90"` but i dont want to change this in the xaml because its also been used my some other app, so instead i want to change that only for this app dynamically based on condition

Comment: Replace Grid with StackPanel with auto Height or no Height in DataTemplate.

Comment: @Jaihind i can tuse stackpanel becuase i have 2 items in each row placed one on left and one on right

Comment: @Goofy could you please share complete code of DataTemplate.

Answer (score 2):

A good way to keep your items synchronized in height is to use a `Grid` with a `ShareSizedScope` :

```
<ListBox Name="TopicListbox" 
                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TitleDataTemplate}"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     SelectionChanged="TopicListboxSelectionChanged"
                     Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TitleDataTemplate">
            <Grid MinHeight="90" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- Your template here -->
            </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Notice the add of `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"` and of a `RowDefinition` with a `SharedSizeGroup`

This will allow your items to all keep the same height as they share a height group

Comment: +1 , but this wont dynamically increase the height of each row

Comment: I use this exact code in a ListBox, synchronizing my columns' width. If any item's width is increased (ie. I selected it), the other items width all increase dynamically. Do you have a different behavior?

Comment: Since i have only 3 items in my list box, the screen is not looking good, so i want to increase the row height

Comment: So you want them to fit the entire listBox space? Try my code with `Height="*"` in the `RowDefinition`. Should work fine

Comment: Ok, i will try with that and get back to you

Comment: can i do it in this way , like add value in resx file and bind it to `MinHeight="{some value}" ` in XAML  ?

Comment: Why would you do that? A `MinHeight` should only be used if you actually need one. If you are trying to work on the height itself, you should rather use `Height`